# Set environmental variables for the command line AND webserver (PHP)

Tags: php, linux, nginx, environment-variables

I am using PHP and NGINX and Mac/linux. I'd like to set environmental variables such that they are accessible from scripts run from the command line or via the webserver.

Setting `$_SERVER` fastcgi params in my nginx configuration doesn't work because then they aren't available in cron jobs that run via the command line.

For security reasons, setting the variables in the web app itself is not a good idea so I don't want to do that either.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Refer to the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.putenv.php. Is that you looking for?

Comment: @Athafoud Thanks, but they can't be set in the script. That's a security issue.

Comment: understood! Why not to dump the variables in a file that both scripts have access? Also if i am not mistaken `cron` runs in a very strict environment, not having full access to the full path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to set `auto_append_file` in `php.ini` to a PHP file that has `setenv()` lines.  Then use `getenv()`.  I'm not sure if OSX has seperate `php.ini` files for web and cli.

Just reread and saw you state Mac/Linux.  For Linux you can set these variables in `/etc/profile` or files in `/etc/profile.d`.  A quick search shows `/etc/launchd.conf` for OSX.  Not sure of the scope of these files but may be worth a try.

Comment: Edited with possible alternative.

Comment: Thanks again, almost done testing your first option on mac. Will get to linux/ubuntu after that and report on both.

Comment: so `auto_append_file` in php.ini with Mac definitely works from the web and cli. I see no reason this solution wouldn't work on any OS. I'm all set thanks!

Comment: Just keep in mind that many Linux distros have separate php.ini for cli and apache.